# SQL Execution error while running parameter query

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, query-builder

Can somebody tell me what i have done wrong in my Parameter query as it does not work?

Basically my intention is to create a search result and display it using DataGridView.

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 1]

These errors appear when I click 'Execute Query' on query builder window.

Below is the SQL Statement

```sql
SELECT        Products.[Product Name], Products.[Product code], [Brands For Sales].[Brand Name], [Main Group].[Group Name], Category.[Catogory Name], SubCatogory.[SubCatogory Name]
FROM            (((((Products INNER JOIN
                     Category ON Products.[Category-ID] = Category.ID) 
INNER JOIN
                     [Brands For Sales] ON Products.[Brand Name] = [Brands For Sales].ID) INNER JOIN
                     [Main Group] ON Products.[Group-ID] = [Main Group].ID AND Category.[Group-ID] = [Main Group].ID) INNER JOIN
                     Category Category_1 ON Products.[Category-ID] = Category_1.ID AND [Main Group].ID = Category_1.[Group-ID]) INNER JOIN
                     SubCatogory ON Products.[SubCategory-ID] = SubCatogory.ID AND Category.ID = SubCatogory.[Catogory-ID] AND Category_1.ID = SubCatogory.[Catogory-ID])
 WHERE        (Products.[Product Name] LIKE '%' + @Searchbox + '%')
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code around that query? I suggest also to remove the % and add them to the parameter value

Comment: I have not used this query anywhere. This error occurs while I am executing the query from Query Builder window, during add new TableAdapter wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Query Builder doesn't support named parameters even for SQL Server, never mind Access.  Replace each of your `@ParameterName` placeholders with `?` and you should be good to go.

EDIT:

The only thing that changes when using positional parameters rather than named parameters (other then the fact that you must add them in the same order as they appear in the SQL, which you should do anyway) is that you cannot reuse a parameter.  That means that you might have to pass the same value twice.  For instance, if you used this SQL with named parameters:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column1 = @SomeValue
OR Column2 = @SomeValue
```

and then you passed a single value to a single parameter to be used twice in the SQL code, you would change the SQL to this with positional parameters:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column1 = ?
OR Column2 = ?
```

and then your command would have two parameters and you would pass the same value to both of them.  That's exactly what everyone already does with Access even if they do name their parameters, because the Jet and ACE OLE DB providers ignore those names and use positions anyway.

Comment: It worked, But in this method how can I compare the parameter value with other fields? For example I want the user to be able to search and find with multiple criteria(Product Name, Product ID, Barcode or even SKU).